# chrome-har-capturer load is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run the following example from https://github.com/eaufavor/chrome-har-capturer-cache

```
var fs = require('fs');
var chc = require('chrome-har-capturer');
var c = chc.load(['https://github.com',
                  'http://www.reddit.com',
                  'http://iwillfail',
                  'http://www.reddit.com/help/faq']);
c.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Chrome');
});
c.on('end', function (har) {
    fs.writeFileSync('out.har', JSON.stringify(har));
});
c.on('error', function () {
    console.error('Cannot connect to Chrome');
});
```

But it returns the following error:

> TypeError: chc.load is not a function

Why do I get this error since the `chrome-har-capturer` module is installed?

Comment: So you installed it with npm?

Comment: yes, `npm install chrome-har-capturer`

Comment: Is chrome-har-capturer in the same directory level as your code? It looks like it didn't load properly, which is probably due to file location.

Comment: Yes, it's installed in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

I think they changed API , now its "run" instead of "load".

Just changed it in my old js file, and it works.

https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer